# how to split overlapping ring polygons by priority order in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial, intersection, overlap

I have a SQL Server spatial layer with 750 circular polygons. Each polygon has a priority number "siteorder") and some of the polygons overlap (in some cases, with multiple others). I would like to split the overlapping areas to only retain it with the circle with the highest siteorder.

I'd ideally like to do this in SQL Server as I also have several steps to perform after this.

I generated the image below in QGIS but it can't easily do the rejoin.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks
Rob
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is to do following algoritm:

1. Loop all circles from highest sortorder to lowest. This simplifies generation of overlapping, since a polygon cannot be overlapped by one in lower sort order
2. Keep track of all previous polygons by generating a "mega polygon" which is a union of all previous. This simplifies overlapping of "lower" sorted polygons.
3. The current polygon will be a difference of the circle and the "mega polygon", ie, rest of the circle that isn't overlapping.

Now for the code, i firstly create some test data in a #t-table, and then make a recursive cte to generate the polygons. You can also use a while loop or cursor if that's simpler

```sql
-- Generate some test data
create table #t_polygons (id int identity, sortorder INT, geomPoint geometry)

declare @i int = 0
,   @geom GEOMETRY
,   @str NVARCHAR(30)
while @i < 700
begin
    set @str = 'POINT (' + CAST(RAND() * 200 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' '
    set @str = @str + CAST(RAND() * 200 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
    set @geom = @str
    insert into #t_polygons (
        sortorder, geomPoint
    )
    select  rand() * 5
    ,   @geom.STBuffer(RAND() * 10)
    set @i = @i + 1
end

select  *
from    #t_polygons

-- Loop through polygons one by one
;with cte as (
    select row_number() OVER(ORDER BY sortorder DESC, id) AS sort
    ,   *
    FROM #t_polygons
)
, cte2 AS (
    select  id
    ,   geomPoint as mergedPoint
    ,   geomPoint AS thisPoint
    ,   sort
    from cte
    WHERE sort = 1
    union all
    select c.id
    ,   mergedPoint.STUnion(geomPoint)
    ,   geomPoint.STDifference(mergedPoint) AS newPoint
    ,   c.sort
    from cte2 c2
    inner join cte c
        ON  c.sort = c2.sort + 1
    
)
select id, thisPoint, sort
from cte2
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: A recursive CTE is a clever solution. Nice!